# Spring rest internationalization

Tags: spring, rest, internationalization

Is there a way to implement Spring internationalization into rest service if I want to setLocale on the parameter i parse from a specific user ticket?

Workflow looks like this: user clicks a link. Service gets user specific ticket and settings. Service parses ticket and gets locale this locale should be set accordingly and then service returns response in a specific language.

All I have found were samples simply transfering locale together with the request. Also I am not getting the point how Spring maps all these names. Do I have to give him the variables and then he maps those names with the language sources given?

Answer (score 8):

You have to create your application localization properties files and put them into the class path, so for e.g. you have two files:

```
application_en.properties
application_lt.properties
```

one is for english language and the other is for lithuanian.
Lets say they contain one property:

```
en:
application.name=Example

lt:
application.name=Pavyzdys
```

Then you have to define a message source in your spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="application"/>
</bean>
```

Please note that basename is `application` and what is beyond underscore: in our case `en` and `lt` is the locale you need to give to message source to get the localized property.

For e.g.:

Lets say you have spring's message source successfully autowired in some bean:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

and you have a method:

```
public String getMessage(String code, String locale) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(code, null, new Locale(locale));
}
```

So when you call:

`getMessage("application.name", "en")` - it will return you "Example" for english language.

`getMessage("application.name", "lt")` - it will return you "Pavyzdys" for lithuanian language.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What about structures of data? If I am sending json objects, normally they have key value pairs. Is it possible to implement this or I need to do additional mapping to get separate variables. Example. DatePreset [{ id: "Yesterday", title: "yesterday" }, { id: "lastWeek", title: "Last week"}].

Comment: All is up to you in this case. You can map your json ids in the localization properties like Yesterday=yesterday and call getMessage("Yesterday", "en"); If your json isn't dynamic it is pretty straightforward. Or even if it is, then you have to know the keys to your properties.

Comment: Yea i think i get the point. I was thinking a bit differently i just need to iterate through my structure. Thanks for the help native guy

Comment: How can I configure the message source in the spring configuration file? I create a project with starters: web, rest services and devtools but I don't see any configuration file. I don't even have the WEB-INF folder

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to get locale inside your rest controller (as far as I understood you are), you can use Message Source. To retrieve message for specific locale just pass it to getMessage().